# JavaPoet : I have created a .java file and want to add to the existing jar file at runtime. How do I do that?

Tags: java, installation, javapoet

I am trying to create a installer for the java project.
I have project say codeGenerator, on making installer the resulting jar would be codeGenrerator.jar
I am trying to use javapoet to create a .java file, but I am not able to write the file to the codeGenerator.jar when I am running the application.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is `codeGenerator` a dependency into your application or is itself the application? If latter, then you can't use javapoet as it only generates java files not compiled classes. To generate code at runtime you should use [javassist](http://www.javassist.org/) or [byte-buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy)

Comment: You need to compile the `.java` into a `.class` file and create a new jar with all the original files and you add files. a `.jar` isn't designed for appending to.

Comment: Can I include the external jars as well to the .jar file that would be created? All these this like creating .java file, compiling to .class and add to jar can be done from java code itself? If yes, how?